# The quadratic equations $x^2+mx-n=0$ and $x^2-mx+n=0$ have integer roots. Prove that $n$ is divisible by $6$.

Tags: number-theory, systems-of-equations, roots, quadratics, discriminant

> **QUESTION:** Suppose that $m$ and $n$ are integers, such that both the quadratic equations $$x^2+mx-n=0$$ and $$x^2-mx+n=0$$ have integer roots. Prove that $n$ is divisible by $6$.

---

**MY APPROACH:**

$\because$ the roots $\in\Bbb{Z}$ therefore, discriminant of the quadratic equations must be a perfect square..

$$\therefore m^2+4n=p^2$$ and $$m^2-4n=q^2$$ for some, $p,q≥0$ and $p,q\in\Bbb{Z}$. Now subtracting these equations we get, $$8n=p^2-q^2$$ $$\implies p^2-q^2\equiv0\pmod{8}$$ Therefore, $p$ and $q$ cannot be of the form $(2×n)$ where $n$ is odd. But this does not seem to help much. So I going back one step, we can write, $$n=\frac{p^2-q^2}{8}$$ But here I am stuck.. I do not know how may I use $8$ with the property of squares to prove that $n$ must be divisible by $6$..

Any help will be much appreciated... Thank you so much :)

Comment: You can show that all possible values of $m$ and $n$  satisfy $$|m|=d\,(u^2+v^2)$$ and $$|n|=d^2\,uv(u+v)|u-v|$$ for some nonnegative integer $d$ and for some pair $(u,v)$ of coprime nonnegative integers of different parity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now as you got $m^2+4n=p^2$ and $m^2-4n=q^2$, we solve further by taking cases.

**Case 1: $m$ is even**

Therefore let $m=2k$ for some positive integer $k$ and by judging the equation we can see that $p$ and $q$ are even too. Let $p=2a$ and $q=2b$ for some positive integers $a$ and $b$. Substituting the values of $m,p$ and $q$, we get $$k^2+n=a^2 \\ k^2-n=b^2$$

This implies $$a^2+b^2=2k^2 \\ a^2-b^2=2n$$

Now let's assume that $n$ is odd, but that would mean $a^2-b^2$ is not divisible by $4$, so either $a^2 \equiv 1\pmod{4}$ and $b^2\equiv 0 \pmod{4}$ or vice versa (Remember that a square is always $\equiv 0~\text{or}~1\pmod{4}$).

Therefore $a^2+b^2\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ in both cases. But we have on the other side $a^2+b^2=2k^2$ which is always either $\equiv 0 \pmod{4}$ or $\equiv 2 \pmod{4}$.

Thus, we get a contradiction. This implies $n$ is even.

Now we assume $n$ is not divisible by $3$ i.e either $2n\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ or $2n\equiv 2\pmod{3}$. Now a square is always either $\equiv 0 ~\text{or}~ 1\pmod{3}$.

Therefore $a^2-b^2=2n\equiv 2\pmod{3}$ is never possible and thus the remaining possibility is $a^2-b^2=2n\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$. This implies $a^2\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ and $b^2\equiv 0\pmod{3}$. Therefore, $a^2+b^2 \equiv 1\pmod{3}$, but we had from the other equation $a^2+b^2=2k^2$ which is always $\equiv 0~\text{or}~2\pmod{3}$. Thus, we get a contradiction. Hence, $n$ is divisible by $3$ as well. Thus, $n$ is divisible by $6$.

Similar analysis goes for the other case where $m$ is odd.

Comment: Thank you so much .. is there a general trend in these sums which helps us think in the right direction? I never seem to get these thoughts, and whatever method comes to my mind, won't give an answer at the end :P

Comment: Well, I don't think there is any general trend. All you need to do is try hard and think in every possible direction. Thoughts automatically start coming and experience also matters though...practice and practice!!!

Comment: I get that. Thank you for your helpful advice :)